# Partial derivatives of $v(x,y) = x f(x+y) + y g(x,y) $

Tags: calculus, derivatives, partial-derivative

For $v(x,y) = x f(x+y) + y g(x+y)$ where $f$ and $g$ are twice differentiable, I need to prove that
$$ v_{xx} - 2v_{xy} + v_{yy} = 0 $$
(it is understood that $v_{xx} = \frac{\partial^2 v}{\partial x^2}$ and $v_{xy} = \frac{\partial^2 v}{\partial x \partial y}$.)

My attempt:
$$v_{xx} = 2f_x(x+y) + xf_{xx}(x+y) + yg_{xx}(x+y),$$
$$v_{yy} =xf_{yy}(x+y) + 2g_y(x+y) + yg_{yy}(x+y),$$
$$-2v_{xy} = -2(f_y(x+y)+ xf_{xy}(x+y)+g_x(x+y)+yg_{xy}(x+y) ).$$

Only the problem is, these terms don't add up to zero! I can't see why. Your help will be appreciated!

Comment: Why don't they add up? Let $z = x+y$. Then $$f_{x} = f' \cdot z_{x}, f_{y} = f' \cdot z_{y} \implies f_{xx} = f'', g_{xx} = g'', f_{yy} = f'', g_{yy} = g''$$ etc, where $' = d/dz$.

Comment: Thanks for the hint but what is the meaning of $f'$ or $f''$ in the context of partial derivatives? Isn't prime notation meant for single-variable differentiation?

Comment: It is a function of a single variable. 'Let $z = x + y$' implies $f(x+y) = f(z(x,y))$. Then $z$ is multivariate function.

Comment: $f$ and $g$ are functions of single variable and you are just evaluating them at $x+y$ to get functions of two variables.

Comment: Thank you Kavi and @mattos I finally figured it out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$f$ and $g$ are functions of a single variable. There are no partial derivatives w.r.t. $x$ and $y$ for these functions. If you replace $f_x$ by $f'$, $f_{xy}$ by $f''$ etc you will see that the given equation is indeed satisfied.

$$v_{xx} = 2f'(x+y) + xf''(x+y) + yg''(x+y),$$
$$v_{yy} =xf''(x+y) + 2g'(x+y) + yg''(x+y),$$
$$-2v_{xy} = -2(f'(x+y)+ xf''(x+y)+g'(x+y)+yg''(x+y) ).$$